# How to use FIrebase Performance to measure by Screen or Context

Tags: flutter, firebase-performance

I'm using Firebase Performance in my flutter project, but it's just measurable the `MainActivity`.

What I like to know is if there is anyway that I can measure by Screen or Context or Scaffold of the Flutter Framework, e.g. Measure the frame rate drop of my HomeScreen.